# Is it possible to use speech to text recognition in languages other than English on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, speech-to-text

I would like to speak in Russian and get it converted into text. Is that even possible? I only have Windows 7 English  edition.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7's in-built Speech Recognition is available in English, French, Spanish, German, Japanese, Simplified Chinese, and Traditional Chinese.

With the English language you will have 2 language options, English (US) and English (UK) to choose from.

If you want to add any of the other available languages, you must install the Language Pack for that language.

The MUI language packs are only available in the Ultimate and Enterprise editions of Windows 7.

For more info check out these MS KB articles:

- [Windows 7 language packs are available for computers that are running Windows 7 Ultimate or Windows 7 Enterprise](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813/)
- [The Windows Speech Recognition language must be the same as the operating system language in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934377)  (Also applies to Windows 7)
- [Setting speech options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Setting-speech-options)